# SpringIntegration Poller copying file

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have setup File poller with task executor

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            LOG.info("Setting up the poller for directory {} ", finalDirectory);
            StandardIntegrationFlow standardIntegrationFlow = IntegrationFlows.from(new CustomFileReadingSource(finalDirectory),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5)
                            .taskExecutor(executorService)
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
                            .advice(new LoggerSourceAdvisor(finalDirectory))
                    ))


                    //move file to processing first processing                    
                    .transform(new FileMoveTransformer("C:/processing", true))
                    .channel("fileRouter")
                    .get();
```

I am using AcceptOnceFilter based using lastUpdated .

Its all working fine the issue I had  was the directory I poll the file come from external system. The file was still being copied and the application picked up and processed partial data.

How can I make sure the file is completely written before I process.

I cannot change the external system as they just copy the files to the folder. They will not change their system.

Answer (score 1):

Please, combine your `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` with the `LastModifiedFileListFilter` to let those files to live in the directory for some time before your start reading them. So, they might be written fully before you pick them up.

See Docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: It looks like this would be more of  a better solution. Probably 30 seconds should do the trick.

Comment: How do  I set the lastmodified time range ?

Comment: There is no range option, however you can come up with the custom filter implementation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot change the external system
>
> How can I make sure the file is completely written before I process.

You can't (reliably).

We provide the `LastModifiedFileListFilter`; you could also monitor the file size, but either way, this is a brittle technique because a network glitch could cause a pause in the file transfer. Also, it depends on the OS (and remote access mechanism) to update these properties while the file is being copied, which might not always be the case.